# Python Pulp model to minimize the inventory

Tags: python, optimization, logistic-regression, inventory, pulp

How can I use Pulp to get minimized Orders for each day? With orders suggested by PuLP, the cumulative stock is always zero.

The below code can only calculate the stock within a day, but it doesn't work when you take cumulative stock into consideration.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pulp

# stock means inventory at the beginning
# Plant stands for inventory located in
# in stands for inventory take in
# out stands for inventory consumption
data = {
    'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04',
             '2020-02-01', '2020-02-08', '2020-02-15', '2020-02-22',
             '2020-02-29', '2020-03-07', '2020-03-15', '2020-03-22'],
    'PartNumber': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'
        , 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'
        , 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    'Plant': ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C'
        , 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'
        , 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'stock': [5, 0, 0, 0
        , 0, 0, 0, 0
        , 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'in': [14, 4, 29, 2
        , 0, 0, 0, 0
        , 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'out': [-10, -25, -8, -8
        , -8, -8, -8, -8
        , -8, -8, -8, -8],
    'Res': [30, 30, 30, 30
        , 30, 30, 30, 30
        , 30, 30, 30, 30]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame ( data, columns=['Date', 'PartNumber', 'Plant', 'stock', 'in', 'out', 'Res'] )
# date , PartNumber ,plant are indexes
df1.set_index ( ['Date', 'PartNumber', 'Plant'], inplace=True )
# in plus out equals the inventory balance with the day
df1['Sum_Stock'] = df1['stock'] + df1['in'] + df1['out']
# cumulative_Stock is the inventory balance

df1['cumulative_Stock'] = df1['Sum_Stock'].cumsum ( axis=0 )
# print ( df1 )
# first step LP minimize
model = pulp.LpProblem ( "MinOrders", pulp.LpMinimize )

# second step create LpVariable
Orders = pulp.LpVariable.dicts ( 'Orders', ((date, PartNumber, Plant) for date, PartNumber, Plant in df1.index),
                                 lowBound=0,
                                 cat='Integer' )

# third steps create object function for PuLP
model += pulp.lpSum (
    [Orders[date, PartNumber, Plant] for date, PartNumber, Plant in
     df1.index]
)
# print ( Orders )
# Forth step create restriction
for date, PartNumber, Plant in df1.index:
    min_AccumulativeStock = df1.loc[(date, PartNumber, Plant), 'Sum_Stock']
    model += Orders[(date, PartNumber, Plant)] + min_AccumulativeStock >= 0
print ( model )
# fifth step solve the
model.solve ( )
# pulp.LpStatus[model.status]
# output
output = []
for date, PartNumber, Plant in Orders:
    var_output = {
        'date': date,
        'PartNumber': PartNumber,
        'Plant': Plant,
        'Orders': Orders[(date, PartNumber, Plant)].varValue
    }
    output.append ( var_output )
output_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ( output ).sort_values ( ['date', 'PartNumber', 'Plant'] )
output_df.set_index ( ['date', 'PartNumber', 'Plant'], inplace=True )
print ( output_df )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7hx5.png)

The objective function is aiming at minimizing the orders for each day.
In my example, the restrictions are: the cumulative stock for each day must be greater than or equals  to  zero.  In other words, if the cumulative  stock reaches to positive or zero, we must stop increasing the orders.
The column RES stands for the restriction for each day of orders. In this example, we can simply ignore this column, because this example is just a simple test. The RES column has not been used in the example.
Later on, I am going to develop a more complex model to solve real problem in logistic inventory control.  For example ,RES (restriction)  orders for each day, transport way (see freight or air freight) will give rise to more complex question.
I suppose that  it’s not a good habit to ask a too complex question at the beginning.
The first step I am doing is to solve this basic problem, regardless the RES (restriction for each day)

Comment: In your example, it's free to order, and `Orders` denotes the number of items ordered. Do you want to minimize the total number of parts ordered? Because in that case, cumulative stock being zero is logical: there is no need to order any sooner! Also, please explain what `Res` means. If possible, add a formal LP definition using LatexAnywhere or an equivalent. It can be an image, that doesn't matter. It's just easier to understand than someone elses code

Comment: hello David Duran, thanks for your help and comments. the comment is limited to 600 words, so I add comments and a picture in my question above.